# Unity Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") and Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) is always false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, keydown

I cannot detect if `space-bar` key was pressed, I have following code:

```
void Update() {
  // Working
  if (Input.anyKeyDown) {
    Debug.Log("anyKeyDown");
  }

  // Not working
  if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
    Debug.Log("GetButtonDown - Jump");
  }

  // Not working
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
    Debug.Log("KeyCode.Space");
  }

  // Working
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
    Debug.Log("A");
  }
}
```

I can detect if e.g. `A` was clicked but its not working for `Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")` or for `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown("space")`

Below you can see image from my console:

[image]

I am using default unity `Input Manager` settings, I can see two `Jumps` configured:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you merge the 2 jumps into one, using the Alt positive button?

Comment: Not working either, basically if I changed `Positive button` for `Jumps` to any other character e.g. `a`, I can detect it by `Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")`. Looks odd. There is info note `Consider using new Input System Package instead`, maybe I will try go this direction

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do not use 2 Jumps declarations in the input editor. Make one and select its axis to X.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, have it in my code snippet: Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown("space")

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        Debug.Log("space key was pressed");
    }
```

instead?

Comment: Yes, have it in my code snippet: `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown("space")`

Comment: Oops, thats on me. In that case my only guess is that it's caused by having 2 inputs with the same name. If you change the latter to something like "JoystickJump" and just add that one as an OR in your IF statement, it may work. Just quessing tho

Comment: Also, maybe you also need to fill out the descriptive name of the input

Comment: Also tried this, changed name of one the input but still without success.

Answer (score 0):

try using `CrossPlatformInputManager`

```
if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton("Space")) {
    Debug.Log("Jump pressed");
}
```

- in Input Manager you can add a secondary button for the same input, like your "joystick button 3" on the first Space input as "Alt Positive Button" (Alternative), so no need to have 2 Space Inputs there.
- why on one Space input you have the "Axis" as "Y Axis" and on the other as "X Axis"? use "X Axis" for both instead.